# Vedana - feelings or sensations?

Tags: personal-practice, theravada, vipassana

I understand feelings as feeling happy, sad, elated, down -  more like an emotion.

Sensations I understand as hot, cold, tingly, numb, all kinds of body pains or pleasant sensations in the body.

Which ones does the Buddha refers to in the Suttas?

I believe they are the sensations in the body and not feelings.

For example is I see a beautiful woman, eye and form, contact -> pleasant sensation in the abdomen -> craving(lust) -> clinging -> becoming and at this stage feeling happy with the beautiful woman form and then a bit sad when I dont see her and prompted by craving I start looking for another beautiful form to cling to and then happy, sad, repeating the cycle again and again.

In my understanding sensations are vedana and not feelings.

Comment: The dejection of not seeing her again is 'death' ('marana').  Eye and form, contact -> pleasant sensation in the abdomen -> craving(lust) -> clinging -> becoming -> birth as lover -> death of lover -> sorrow, saddness, despair, grief, dukkha. This is the cycle of birth & death; gain & loss; samsara.

Answer (score 1):

This question is about words. The Pali words are 'vedana' ('feelings') & 'sankhara' ('formations').

Happy, sad, elated, down - more like an emotion = sankhara ('formations'). To quote:

> *When one abides inflamed by lust, fettered, infatuated, contemplating gratification, then the five aggregates affected by clinging are built
>   up for oneself in the future; and one’s craving—which brings renewal
>   of being, is accompanied by delight and lust, and delights in this and
>   that—increases. One’s bodily and mental troubles increase, one’s
>   bodily and mental torments increase, one’s bodily and mental fevers
>   increase and one experiences bodily and mental suffering (kāyadukkhampi cetodukkhampi paṭisaṃvedeti). MN 149*

Hot, cold, tingly, numb, all kinds of body pains or pleasant sensations = 'vedana'. To quote:

> *And why, bhikkhus, do you call it feeling (vedanaṃ)? ‘It feels (vedayatī),’ bhikkhus, therefore it is called feeling. And what does it feel? It
>   feels pleasure, it feels pain, it feels neither-pain-nor-pleasure. ‘It
>   feels,’ bhikkhus, therefore it is called feeling. SN 22.79*

But some body pains are formations, such as when due to anger, stress, anxiety, etc. To quote:

> *When one abides inflamed by lust, fettered, infatuated, contemplating gratification, then the five aggregates affected by clinging are built
>   up for oneself in the future; and one’s craving—which brings renewal
>   of being, is accompanied by delight and lust, and delights in this and
>   that—increases. One’s bodily and mental troubles increase, one’s
>   bodily and mental torments increase, one’s bodily and mental fevers
>   increase and one experiences bodily and mental suffering (kāyadukkhampi cetodukkhampi paṭisaṃvedeti). MN 149*

The core feature of 'vedana' ('feelings' or 'sensations') is they arise from sense contact. To quote:

> *‘The six classes of feeling should be understood.’ So it was said. And with reference to what was this said? Dependent on the eye and
>   forms, eye-consciousness arises; the meeting of the three is contact;
>   with contact as condition there is feeling. Dependent on the ear and
>   sounds, ear-consciousness arises; the meeting of the three is contact;
>   with contact as condition there is feeling. Dependent on the nose and
>   odours, nose-consciousness arises; the meeting of the three is
>   contact; with contact as condition there is feeling. Dependent on the
>   tongue and flavours, tongue-consciousness arises; the meeting of the
>   three is contact; with contact as condition there is feeling.
>   Dependent on the body and tangibles, body-consciousness arises; the
>   meeting of the three is contact; with contact as condition there is
>   feeling. Dependent on the mind and mind-objects, mind-consciousness
>   arises; the meeting of the three is contact; with contact as condition
>   there is feeling. So it was with reference to this that it was said:
>   ‘The six classes of feeling should be understood. ’ This is the fifth
>   set of six. MN 148*

Where as formations arise from defilement (craving) & thinking (sankhara). To quote:

> *What one feels, one perceives (labels in the mind). What one perceives, one **thinks** about. What one **thinks** about, one **objectifies**.
>   Based on what a person **objectifies**, the perceptions & **categories of
>   objectification assail him/her** with regard to past, present & future
>   forms cognizable via the eye. MN 18*

Comment: So I think you're saying that, saying that "That is a tingling feeling" is a *vedana*. What about saying "That tingling is a **nice** feeling or a **nasty** feeling" ... is that vedana too? I'm not sure I've caught the difference between vedana, sanna, and sankhara.

Comment: That is Papanka, but formations can arise without craving and defilement as the Buddha and Arahants speak and think without defilement and craving